# Customize Calendar Portlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am new to this Liferay.I drag and drop the Calendar Portlet from Collabaration.Is there any way to customize the Calendar Portlet.I want to show only the Calendar and the events added by admin.

Comment: Calendar portlet displays all the events created by user (user having add events rights) so its not just events created by admin.. I am not sure what your exact requirement is ? whether other users will have the right to create the calendar events or not ? you need filtering ? you could customize based on your requirements by creating hook. share more details on what you are looking for ?

Comment: Which Liferay version? In LF 6.2 Calendar is brand new.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible to change the permission for each calendar. So you can configure who has access to manage events:

[image]